# Put request doen't reach backend api

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to send a put request to my backend api, but I need a token and its working on the get request so the problem isn't with the token but when I make the request the response is 202 accepted and don't update the database.

Here is the code

```
    <resource methods="PUT" uri-template="/Nurse">
    <inSequence>
        <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="body"/>
            <target property="payload" type="property"/>
        </enrich>
        <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
        <call blocking="true" description="">
            <endpoint>
                <address format="get" uri="http://192.168.20.1:8280/loginAPI/login"/>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <property expression="json-eval($.accessToken)" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="fn:concat('Bearer ',$ctx:token)" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <enrich description="Restore original payload">
            <source property="payload" type="property"/>
            <target type="body"/>
        </enrich>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="PutNurseEp"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

Can anyone help what is the problem here?

Comment: Please enable wire logs and post the logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the question, the error was on the postman request, I was adding a space on the beggining of the url